# Backing Up MySQL's Data

Tags: mysql, laravel-4

As while using Laravel, we have an option to seed our database or create tables anytime, like

```
class UsersTableSeeder extends Seeder 
{

    public function run()
    {
        User::truncate();
        User::create([
            'username' => 'Junaid',
            'email' => 'darulehsan03@gmail.com',
            'password' => '1234'
            ]);
        User::create([
            'username' => 'Junaid Farooq',
            'email' => 'aba@bcd.com',
            'password' => '4321'
            ]);
    }

}
```

we can seed our database anytime, but what if we have a large no of rows in our table, which are not being seeded but added by the users , then how can we put it that way, like a Seeder file so, anytime at anyplace , we can load all those rows through our Seeder File?
not asking about to save .SQL file and then import or Export it, But a way to backup them in a Seeder file

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of any method of backing up the data to a seed file. You can, like you've already said, export and import your data.

There are also a couple of packages available to backup and restore a database.

1. [`laravel-backup`](https://github.com/schickling/laravel-backup), which seems to be a Laravel-specific package that allows you to backup your database and restore it.
2. [`database-backup`](https://github.com/ShawnMcCool/database-backup), which is framework agnostic but does come with a Laravel service provider for easier integration with Laravel.

Both seem to allow you to backup and restore from Amazon S3. Having used neither I can't say which is better or why. You'll have to try both out and make that decision for yourself.

Comment: not am asking about to happen this automatically, when we put our SITE online who has such time to make backup of all the database by himself or rather to has it in safe automatically and can change it to another hosting or domain when ever want to

Comment: Set up a cron job then.